# GRASS GIS cannot open

Tags: grass-gis, data

I am a newer using GRASS. I have tried to open the data named "nc_spm_08". But it couldn't open because errors as fallows:

```
       __________  ___   __________    _______________

GRASS GIS homepage:                      http://grass.osgeo.org
This version running through:            Bash Shell (/bin/bash)
Help is available with the command:      g.manual -i
See the licence terms with:              g.version -c
See citation options with:               g.version -x
If required, restart the GUI with:       g.gui wxpython
When ready to quit enter:                exit

Launching <wxpython> GUI in the background, please wait...
GRASS 7.2.svn (nc_spm_08):~ > ERROR 1: dlopen(/Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
ERROR 1: dlopen(/Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
ERROR 1: dlopen(/Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_MG4Lidar.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/Libraries/liblti_lidar_dsdk.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_MG4Lidar.dylib
  Reason: image not found
ERROR 1: dlopen(/Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_MG4Lidar.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/Libraries/liblti_lidar_dsdk.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_MG4Lidar.dylib
  Reason: image not found
ERROR 1: dlopen(/Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_MrSID.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/Libraries/libltidsdk.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_MrSID.dylib
  Reason: image not found
ERROR 1: dlopen(/Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_MrSID.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/Libraries/libltidsdk.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/GDAL/2.1/PlugIns/gdal_MrSID.dylib
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/GDAL
  Referenced from: /Applications/GRASS-7.2.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/g.version
  Reason: image not found
Unable to get GRASS version
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/GDAL
  Referenced from: /Applications/GRASS-7.2.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/g.version
  Reason: image not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.2.app/Contents/MacOS/scripts/g.extension", line 1726, in <module>
    version = grass_version['version'].split('.')
KeyError: 'version'
GRASS 7.2.svn (nc_spm_08):~ >
```

I have installed all frameworks so I don't know how to do.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Check GDAL supported formats using: "gdalinfo --formats", is JP2ECW included? Try to open your raster with "gdalinfo your_file", if it fails the problem is with GDAL not GRASS.

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed all frameworks so I don't know how to do.

- You have not installed the GDAL 1.11  framework (`dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/GDAL`)
- The rest are Gdal plugins, `gdal_MG4Lidar`, `gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dylib`, `gdal_MrSID.dylib`, not indispensable for running Grass (only the [GRASS plugin](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL-GRASS_Plugin-2.1.1-2.dmg))

[image]

- in the GRASS shell, type

  GRASS 7.2.svn (nc_spm_08):~ >  g.gui wxpython